# Failing to download image by URL with Python

Tags: python, image, web-crawler, urllib2

I want to use python to download image to local directory by its url.
My way is to use “urllib2” package to download. The code is

```
def download(url, filename):
f = open(filename, "wb")
headers = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6'}
req = urllib2.Request(url=url, headers=headers)

f.write(urllib2.urlopen(req, timeout=10).read())
f.close()
```

I succeeded in most of the urls, but for some url I failed even though with more timeout seconds.

Some failing example of these “strange” urls:

https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/c0/95/5d/c0955d6d0ffe6145924d4e7d252cde4e.jpg
https://smhttp-ssl-33667.nexcesscdn.net/manual/wp-content/uploads/2016/10/navy-suit-blue-shirt-men-look.jpg
http://1.bp.blogspot.com/ExAqpPuUKM4/Uzq6mXbda2I/AAAAAAAAEL4/c_xgff8HMNU/s1600/1890361_801417276554561_1726056762_o.jpg

I used ”try” and “excpet” to get the excpetion.  
try:
download(url, filename)
except Exception, e:
print Exception, ‘:’, e

There are several kinds of errors :

```
<type 'exceptions.Exception'> : <urlopen error [Errno 65] No route to host>
<type 'exceptions.Exception'> : [Errno 54] Connection reset by peer
<type 'exceptions.Exception'> : timed out
```

I tried other download tools, but they didn't work either. But when I try to use a browser like Chrome or Safari, the images are well loaded.

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: according to the exceptions, looks like you are getting network issues or the remote end are having problems. I tried downloading them using requests and it just works from my location.

Answer (score 0):

```
imgRequest = urllib2.Request(imgUrl, headers=headers)
imgData = urllib2.urlopen(imgRequest).read())
```

but a more convinient way would be to use urllib.urlretrieve

```
import urllib
urllib.urlretrieve("http://www.image.com/00000001.jpg", "00000001.jpg")
```